# VB.NET - Fill Specific Column DataGridView from Another Column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have 2 DGV name `dataListBarang` and `dataListTransaksi`, i'm trying to fill `dataListTransaksi` spesific column called `nama_barang` from specific column in `dataListBarang` called `nm_barang`

my code so far

```
Private Sub dataListBarang_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListBarang.CellContentDoubleClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
            namaBarang = Me.dataListBarang.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            dataListTransaksi.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = namaBarang
        End If
        dataListBarang.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

when i double click on DGV `dataListBarang`, column `nama_barang` (on `dataListTransaksi`) will filled with value from column `nm_barang` on DGV `dataListBarang`, but its not working.

please help.

**EDIT**
what i'm trying to do is copy cell from current row when user double click on it then fill the first row on second DataGrid (dataGrid has columns with no data in it) in specific column.

[image]

note:

1. see the left dataGrid has data and the right dataGrid is empty
2. see the number!, when user double click, the value from 1 is copied to number 2
3. most of column in right dataGrid is manually input (except Nama Barang) and save to database

Comment: Are you trying to copy the whole column or just the cell? In addition, are the grids data bound? Setting the target columns DataPropertyName… obviously will not work.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to copy cell in column, the first dgv (`dataListBarang`) is data bound (read from table) but second dgv (`dataTransaksiBarang`) isn't, because the second dgv is manually input (insert to table).

Comment: If you are copying a single cell... where would you copy this cell to in the other grid? Example, the user double clicks the cell in row 3 column 3 in the first grid... would you copy this cell into the same row and column in the other grid?

Comment: no, the value from first datagrid is copied to another row and column in the other datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your picture shows is an empty `DataGridView` on the right. When you copy the cell from the left grid to the cell in the right grid as the picture shows, will have some problems. You will have to “Add” a new row first. Otherwise, subsequent double clicks from the user will simply overwrite the previous double click. The code below checks to see if the double click came from column 0 and if so simply adds a new row to the grid on the right. The value in column 0 is copied to the new row column 1. Hope I am not missing something.

```
Private Sub dataListBarang_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListBarang.CellContentDoubleClick
  Dim row As Integer = e.RowIndex
  Dim col As Integer = e.ColumnIndex
  If (col = 0) Then
    dataListTransaksi.Rows.Add("", dataListBarang.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value)
  End If
End Sub
```

Update: If you do not know which column to copy but you know its name..

```
Private Sub dataListBarang_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListBarang.CellContentDoubleClick
  Dim row As Integer = e.RowIndex
  Dim col As Integer = e.ColumnIndex
  If (col = 0) Then
    Dim newRowIndex As Integer = dataListTransaksi.Rows.Add()
    dataListTransaksi.Rows(newRowIndex).Cells("MyColName").Value = dataListBarang.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @JhonG, i made my solution based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i modified my code based on answer by @JhonG

```
 Private Sub dataListBarang_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataListBarang.CellContentDoubleClick
        Dim row As Integer = e.RowIndex
        Dim col As Integer = e.ColumnIndex
        namaBarang = Me.dataListBarang.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        If (col = 0) Then

            If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
                dataListTransaksi.Rows.Add("", namaBarang)
                'hargaBarang = Me.dataListBarang
                'Me.dataListTransaksi.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = namaBarang
            End If
        End If
```

when i double click in firstDataGrid it copy the value to another dataGrid and add new row.

Comment: I could be wrong here... but checking to see if "e"s row or column is less than zero is unnecessary since double clicking outside the grid will NOT fire this event. You can pretty much guarantee a valid cell here, even the new row double click will not fire this event. Just a thought.